# asp.net viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult AddDinner()
{
  Dinner dinner = dinnerRepository.GetDinner(id);
  ViewData["dinner"] = repository.AllDinners();

  return View(dinner);
}
```

1) First, are both the dinner object and the `ViewData["dinner"]` is passing to the view?

2) Second, how would I iterate over the `ViewData["dinner"]` in the view?

Comment: You should change either the `dinner` variable name or the key of the `ViewData` item. (Unless they contain the same thing.) Using the same name makes it hard to understand the question: imagine how much harder it will be to read your view's code.

Comment: @Jeff: totally, it's kind of confusing when you first read it :)  
@mazhar: change it to ViewData["dinners"] or sth :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. Both `dinner` and ViewData["dinner"] will be available on the page. You can access `dinner` via the `Model` in the `View`.

2.

```
<% foreach(Dinner d in (IEnumerable<Dinner>)ViewData["dinner"])
   {
       // Code goes here 
   } %>
```

Comment: this is actually completely FALSE! =/

Comment: @Artiom Chilaru - You're right. I completely mis-read the code. I'm upding my answer to reflect.

Comment: @mazhar: See, @Jeff told you it was confusing! :D

Comment: @Artiom Chilaru - Look a little better?

Comment: @Justin yup, much better )
I can't edit my previous comment though... So saying it here- it's not false anymore :P

Comment: I am not able to get any intellisence of the object by using d? How would I do that

Answer (score 4):

1) Yes, both will be available in your view. So nothing to worry :)

2) While the data you pass to the View() method will be available from the view's Model object, you can access all the data you set in the ViewData[] set by reading them from... ViewData[]! ^_^

So anywhere in your view, you can do this:

```
<% foreach(Dinner d in ViewData["dinner"] as IEnumerable<Dinner>)
{
    RenderPartial("Dinner", d);
} %>
```

Or something like that :)